# Table View Not ReloadData after Unfollow User swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase when I follow user his post show up nicely in the `UITableView` . but when unfollow him , his post still in the `UITableView`. `UITableView` not reloading data after unfollow.

View Controller :

```
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import SDWebImage
class HomeVC: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewOutLet: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var postContentArray = [Post]() // contine all Posts .
    var userContentArray = [UserModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewOutLet.dataSource = self
        tableViewOutLet.estimatedRowHeight = 521
        tableViewOutLet.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        loadPosts()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }


    @objc func loadPosts () {
      //  activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        API.Feed.ObserveFeedWithMyPostAndFollowerPost(withid: API.User.Curren_User!.uid) { (postr) in

            self.fetchUserInfo(PostUserID: postr.userPostId!, Completed: {
            self.postContentArray.append(postr)
          //  self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            self.tableViewOutLet.reloadData()

                            })
        }

        API.Feed.ObserveFeedReomved(withid: API.User.Curren_User!.uid) { (key) in
            // print(key)

            self.postContentArray = self.postContentArray.filter {$0.userPostId != key }
            self.tableViewOutLet.reloadData()
        }
    }




    @objc func fetchUserInfo (PostUserID : String , Completed : @escaping ()-> Void) {

        API.User.observeUserInformation(CommentUserID: PostUserID) { (User) in
            self.userContentArray.append(User)
            Completed()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logOutButton(_ sender: Any) {

        AuthServices.logout(OnSuccess: {
        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "تم تسجيل الخروج")
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
            let signInvc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC")
            self.present(signInvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }) { (error) in
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error)
        }

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "commentIconSequeToCommentPage" {
            let commentvc = segue.destination as! CommentsVC
            commentvc.postID = sender as? String
        }
    }
}

extension HomeVC: UITableViewDataSource  {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postContentArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let postContent = postContentArray[indexPath.row]
        let userContent = userContentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.postContent = postContent
        cell.userContentInfo = userContent

        cell.homeView = self
        return cell
    }

}
```

Observe Functions :

```
import Foundation
import  FirebaseDatabase
class FeedAPI {
    var REF_FEED = Database.database().reference().child("Feed")

    func ObserveFeedWithMyPostAndFollowerPost (withid id : String , complation : @escaping (Post)->Void) {
        REF_FEED.child(id).observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshto : DataSnapshot) in
            let key = snapshto.key
            API.Post.observePostFuntion(withID: key, Complation: { (post) in
             complation(post)
            })
        }
    }

    func ObserveFeedReomved (withid id : String , complation : @escaping (String)->Void) {
        REF_FEED.child(id).observe(DataEventType.childRemoved) { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in
            let key = snapshot.key

            complation(key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where exactly is the unfollow function?

Also you should set the tableview delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 tableViewOutLet.delegate = self
}
```

Please show where exactly are you preforming the unfollow function.

Answer (score 0):

my follow And unfollow func

```
class FollowAPI {
    var REF_FOLLOWERS = Database.database().reference().child("Follower")
    var REF_FOLLOWING = Database.database().reference().child("Following")


    func followAction (withId id : String) {

        API.Follow.REF_FOLLOWERS.child(id).child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).setValue(true)

        API.Follow.REF_FOLLOWING.child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).child(id).setValue(true)
        API.myPOSTS.REF_MYPOSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot :  DataSnapshot) in
            print(snapshot.key)
            if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{
                for key in dic.keys {
                    API.Feed.REF_FEED.child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).child(key).setValue(true)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func UnFollowAction (withid id : String) {

        API.Follow.REF_FOLLOWERS.child(id).child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).setValue(NSNull())
        API.Follow.REF_FOLLOWING.child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).child(id).setValue(NSNull())

        API.myPOSTS.REF_MYPOSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot :  DataSnapshot) in
            print(snapshot.key)
            if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]{
                for key in dic.keys {
                    API.Feed.REF_FEED.child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).child(key).removeValue()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func isFollwoing (userid : String , Complated : @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
        REF_FOLLOWERS.child(userid).child(API.User.Curren_User!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot ) in

            if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
                Complated(false)
            } else {

                Complated(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```